# How would I restructure this query to line up the data accordingly?

Tags: plsql, decode, resultset

```
select distinct
a.contcode,
decode(d.period,1,d.factor)"1YR",
decode(d.period,2,d.factor)"2YR",
decode(d.period,3,d.factor)"3YR",
decode(d.period,4,d.factor)"4YR",
decode(d.period,5,d.factor)"5YR"
from contlink a
join plans b on a.plangrp = b.plangrp
join earnings_account_classes c on a.contcode = c.account_class_code
join earnings_factors d on c.account_class_id = d.account_class_id
where b.program in ('AT','EIPP','RUP','WP','CW','MCK','PDR','TW','WR','WRR')
and b.term in (12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120)
and a.end_date is null
order by 1;
```

Data currently looks like this:

| CONTCODE | 1YR | 2YR | 3YR | 4YR | 5YR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 8.33 |  |  |  |  |
| A03 | 4.56 |  |  |  |  |
| A03 |  | 3.78 |  |  |  |
| A05 | 2.75 |  |  |  |  |
| A05 |  | 3.26 |  |  |  |
| A05 |  |  | 2.33 |  |  |
| A07 | 2.42 |  |  |  |  |
| A07 |  | 2.69 |  |  |  |
| A07 |  |  | 2.23 |  |  |
| A07 |  |  |  | 0.99 |  |
| A09 | 2.37 |  |  |  |  |
| A09 |  | 2.32 |  |  |  |
| A09 |  |  | 1.80 |  |  |
| A09 |  |  |  | 1.21 |  |
| A09 |  |  |  |  | 0.65 |

I need it to look like this:

| CONTCODE | 1YR | 2YR | 3YR | 4YR | 5YR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 8.33 |  |  |  |  |
| A03 | 4.56 | 3.78 |  |  |  |
| A05 | 2.75 | 3.26 | 2.33 |  |  |
| A07 | 2.42 | 2.69 | 2.23 | 0.99 |  |
| A09 | 2.37 | 2.32 | 1.80 | 1.21 | 0.65 |

Please advise.

Comment: What you are looking for is to PIVOT the results. Fortunately provides an extension to SQL for just this purpose. See [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/). Also when pasting text do not just past it - you need to format it.  For this I just places the text you had between lines containing only ```. For a slightly better process see [here](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-pivot/);

Comment: Thanks! I had to go learn how to PIVOT. Totally worked.

Comment: That's good! I figure that is the best the community can do.  We share our knowledge allowing you to figure it out, and increase your knowledge in the process. Now just pass it forward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
select distinct
a.contcode,
sum(decode(d.period,1,d.factor))"1YR",
sum(decode(d.period,2,d.factor))"2YR",
sum(decode(d.period,3,d.factor))"3YR",
sum(decode(d.period,4,d.factor))"4YR",
sum(decode(d.period,5,d.factor))"5YR"
...
group by a.contcode
order by 1;
```

Bobby